# two separate joins on one query; counting all messages to and from one user

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I'm trying to figure out how I can show the count of messages sent a received by each user in a database.  I have a table of users, where I want to pull the userid (called id) and the username, and a table of messages, which have an id, a fromid (fkey from users), a toid (fkey from users), and a body (the text of the message).  The result would be like this:

```
id | username | tocount | fromcount
1  | user1    | 2       | 3
2  | user2    | 1       | 1
3  | user3    | 3       | 1
4  | lastuser | 0       | 1
```

How can I accomplish this?  I've tried a number of different join combinations, but I end up getting inaccurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `union all` followed by `group by`:

```
select userid, sum(fromnum) as fromcnt, sum(tonum) as tocnt
from ((select fromid as userid, 1 as fromnum, 0 as tonum
       from messages
      ) union all
      (select toid as userid, 0, 1
       from messages
      )
     ) ft
group by userid;
```